# Query in Wordpress of a Custom Post Type with the postmeta

Tags: mysql, wordpress, shortcode, meta-key, post-meta

I am trying to make a wordpress shortcode with a query.
I have to make a query of how many orders were made of the products in the last day and in the last week.

I don't know how to filter by date (the date is also in text format).
Thank you very much.

Until now I did this:

The Table:

| post_id | meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 164 | order_date | 09-12-2020 18:17 |
| 164 | order_items_5_order_product | chcolate |
| 164 | order_items_6_order_product | menta |
| 165 | order_date | 05-12-2020 14:35 |
| 165 | order_items_1_order_product | chcolate |
| 165 | order_items_2_order_product | menta |
| 165 | order_items_3_order_product | granizo |
| 166 | order_date | 02-10-2020 11:37 |
| 166 | order_items_5_order_product | chcolate |
| 166 | order_items_6_order_product | menta |

Query:

> SELECT meta_value, COUNT(*) Totales_Pedidos FROM tc_10_postmeta um
> WHERE meta_key LIKE "order_items_%_order_product" GROUP BY meta_value
> ORDER BY Totales_Pedidos desc

Result:

| meta_key | Totales_Pedidos |
| --- | --- |
| chcolate | 3 |
| menta | 3 |
| granizo | 1 |

Shortcode:

```
function fln_table_shortcode() {
 global $wpdb;
 $html = "";
 $result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT meta_value, COUNT(*) Totales_Pedidos FROM tc_10_postmeta um WHERE meta_key LIKE "order_items_%_order_product" GROUP BY meta_value ORDER BY Totales_Pedidos desc');
 $count = $wpdb->num_rows;
 if($count >0){
  $html .="<table>";    
    $html .="<tr><td><strong>PRODUCT</strong></td><td><strong>NUMBER OF ORDERS</strong></td></tr>";
    $html .="<tr>";
  foreach($result as $r){
    $html .="<td>".$r->meta_value."</td>";
    $html .="<td>".$r->Totales_Pedidos."</td>";
    $html .="</tr>";
   }
  $html .="</table>";
}

return $html;
}
add_shortcode( 'table_shortcode','fln_table_shortcode');
```

Comment: ola aqui tinenes escribir en ingles o visita  https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: sorry, I translated it there.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you must use a pivot table and prepared statements to generate a dynamic table

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tc_10_postmeta 
>     (`post_id` int, `meta_key` varchar(27), `meta_value` varchar(16))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO tc_10_postmeta 
>     (`post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`)
> VALUES
>     (164, 'order_date', '09-12-2020 18:17'),
>     (164, 'order_items_5_order_product', 'chcolate'),
>     (164, 'order_items_6_order_product', 'menta'),
>     (165, 'order_date', '05-12-2020 14:35'),
>     (165, 'order_items_1_order_product', 'chcolate'),
>     (165, 'order_items_2_order_product', 'menta'),
>     (165, 'order_items_3_order_product', 'granizo'),
>     (166, 'order_date', '02-10-2020 11:37'),
>     (166, 'order_items_5_order_product', 'chcolate'),
>     (166, 'order_items_6_order_product', 'menta')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>     `post_id`,
>     MAX(IF(`meta_key` = 'order_date', STR_TO_DATE(`meta_value`, '%m-%d-%Y %H:%i'), NULL ))  as ORDERDate
>     , SUM(IF(`meta_key`  LIKE "order_items_%_order_product" AND  `meta_value` = 'chcolate',1,0)) as 'chcolate'
>     ,SUM(IF(`meta_key`  LIKE "order_items_%_order_product" AND  `meta_value` = 'menta',1,0)) as 'menta'
>     ,SUM(IF(`meta_key`  LIKE "order_items_%_order_product" AND  `meta_value` = 'granizo',1,0)) as 'granizo'
> FROM tc_10_postmeta
> GROUP BY `post_id`
> ```
>
> ```
> post_id | ORDERDate           | chcolate | menta | granizo
> ------: | :------------------ | -------: | ----: | ------:
>     164 | 2020-09-12 18:17:00 |        1 |     1 |       0
>     165 | 2020-05-12 14:35:00 |        1 |     1 |       1
>     166 | 2020-02-10 11:37:00 |        1 |     1 |       0
> ```

> ```
> SET @sql ='';
> SELECT 
>   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
>     CONCAT(
>       'SUM(IF(`meta_key`  LIKE "order_items_%_order_product" AND  `meta_value` = "',
>      `meta_value`,
>       '",1,0)) AS "',
>       `meta_value`, '"'      
>     )
>   ) 
>   INTO @sql
> FROM tc_10_postmeta
> WHERE `meta_key`  LIKE "order_items_%_order_product";
> SET @sql = CONCAT('select `post_id`
>                   ,MAX(IF(`meta_key` = "order_date", STR_TO_DATE(`meta_value`, "%m-%d-%Y %H:%i"), NULL ))  as ORDERDate
>                   ,',@sql,' from tc_10_postmeta
>                   group by `post_id`');
>
> PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
> EXECUTE stmt;
> DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
> ```
>
> ```
> post_id | ORDERDate           | chcolate | granizo | menta
> ------: | :------------------ | -------: | ------: | ----:
>     164 | 2020-09-12 18:17:00 |        1 |       0 |     1
>     165 | 2020-05-12 14:35:00 |        1 |       1 |     1
>     166 | 2020-02-10 11:37:00 |        1 |       0 |     1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=35f1b70530f8a9ef02b0f3ef618e1dbf)*